# Error in Python

Tags: python

This is my 1st Python program.I implemented a dictionary as shown below. Here I'm trying to retrieve values**(either key or value)** depending upon the user input.

For eg: If user enters "1" then I need to retrieve "Sachin Tendulkar " from the dictioanry. If user enter "Sachin Tendulkar" then I need to retrieve "1" from dictioanry.

```
streetno={"1":"Sachin Tendulkar","2":"Sehawag","3":"Dravid","4":"Dhoni","5":"Kohli"}
while True:
     inp=input('Enter M/N:')
if inp=="M" or inp=="m":
    key=raw_input( "Enter the main number :")
    result=streetno.get(key)
else:
      key=raw_inp("Enter the street name : ")
        result=streetno.get(key)
```

I think there's nothing wrong with the logic. But i'm not able to execute it. I'm getting below shown error.

```
Python 2.7.2 (default, Jun 12 2011, 14:24:46) [MSC v.1500 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
Type "copyright", "credits" or "license()" for more information.
>>> ================================ RESTART ================================
>>> 
Enter M/N:m

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\kiran\Desktop\Cricketpur.py", line 3, in <module>
 inp=input('Enter M/N:')
File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'm' is not defined
>>>
```

Comment: You mix `input` (which you really should, as it opens a large security hole), `raw_input` and `raw_inp`, the latter of which does not exist. Also, are you aware that indentation is part of the logic of a Python program?

Comment: -1: Terrible question title.  This appears to be a "variable not defined" question.  Please fix your title so other people can learn from it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is within this line:

```
inp=input('Enter M/N:')
```

You use `input` instead of `raw_input`, which you really shouldn't, as it executes everything the user inputs *as Python code*. Just use `raw_input` here and it should be fine.

However, the rest of your code is also broken and shouldn't work as you expect it to work. My attempt at fixing it:

```
streetno = { "1" : "Sachin Tendulkar",
             "2" : "Sehawag",
             "3" : "Dravid",
             "4" : "Dhoni",
             "5" : "Kohli"}

# we create a "reversed" dictionary here that maps
# names to numbers
streetname = dict((y,x) for x,y in streetno.items())

while True:
    inp = raw_input('Enter M/N:')
    if inp == "M" or inp == "m":
        key = raw_input("Enter the main number:")
        # you don't need .get here, a simple [] is probably what you want
        result = streetno[key]
    else:
        key = raw_input("Enter the street name: ")
        # we need to use our reversed map here!
        result = streetname[key]

    # do something with the result (change that to whatever you want
    # to do with it)
    print result
```

Comment: `streetname = dict((y,x) for x,y in streetno.items())` is a great idiom. Thx.

Comment: @Finn: Actually in Python >= 2.7, which has dict comprehensions, the idiom is `{y:x for x,y in d.iteritems()}` (only `items` in Python 3). Suprisingly, the following is even faster in Python 2.7 (but *not* in Python 3, it seems!): `{d[k]:k for k in d}`

Comment: even slicker, but both unequivocally better than using zip with unpacking which is what I was fumbling around w/.

Answer (score 2):

If you want a character typed in use raw_input, not input (which takes an expression and tries to evaluate it), and not raw_inp (which doesn't exist).

Also, your 'while True' expression is never going to end.

And you haven't indented your 'else' clause properly.

Comment: I think the OP wants the program to continue indefinitely, hence the infinite "while True" loop.

Comment: How about this?  inp=input('Enter M/N:')

Comment: Yes.. I want to the program to continue indefinitely.

Comment: @Kiran: You can't use `input` here. You need `raw_input`.

Comment: You need to indent *everything* after the while to make the whole thing loop. As it stands (or as it looks here) it'll just keep asking for input for M/N

Answer (score 2):

The problem looks like you are using `input` for the first question (you are using `raw_input` for the others)

As a side note, you may want to check out python's built-in module `cmd` for this kind of program. It's specifically for creating command line programs like this:

http://www.doughellmann.com/PyMOTW/cmd/

Answer (score 1):

Since you're using Python 2.7, `input()` behaves like `eval(raw_input())`, which means it's evaluating what's coming in as input.  Change that to `raw_input()`.  Also, `raw_inp` isn't a function so you'd need to change that to `raw_input()` as well.

There are some indentation issues as well; you should make sure that everything is properly indented.  It also seems your loop will not end.